# Change mp3 src attribute works in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, audio

I want to switch src attribute of an embedded mp3.

```
  <embed id="aplayer" width="10" height="10" src="audio/gong.mp3">
```

JS

```
$("#btnPlay").click(function() {
    if (mm==0) {
    $('#aplayer').attr('src', 'audio/01.mp3');
    mm = 1;
    }
    else {
    $('#aplayer').attr('src', 'audio/gong.mp3');
    mm = 0;
}
```

Works in Firefox (the new file plays), but not in Chrome.

Is there a way to solve this in Chrome ?

Comment: some browsers dont support mp3 format use .ogg format to support them.

Comment: @maverickosama92, supporting matters only using html5 audio tag. And, in that case Chrome, and not Firefox supports mp3. Current mp3 plays normally in both browsers, because it is embedded.